# Parsing xml to get the all nodes between two nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing, siblings

Hi I have an xml as below:

```
>     <body>
>         <p>
> 
>             <xxx>
>                 <txt>{{<txt>
>             </xxx>
>             <Err type="Start"/>
>             <xxx>
>                 <txt>f</txt>
>             </xxx>
>             <xxx>
>                 <txt>irst_name</txt>
>             </xxx>
>             <Err type="End"/>
>             <xxx>
>                 <txt>}}</txt>
>             </xxx>
>         <p> </body>
```

So I am trying to get everything between

> `<Err type="Start"/> .... <Err type="End"/>`

and then extract the txt node values to get an outpput of "firstName"

this is what I have so far but a bit lost after this please Help.

```
xml =  $(mainXMl).find('p')
    $(xml).each(function(wPrgs){
       var parentEle = $(xml[wPrgs]).find('Err')
           $(parentEle).each(function(childEle){
             $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib) {
                   if(attrib.name === "type" && attrib.value === "Start"){
                       var end= childEle===parentEle.length-1 ? parentEle.nextSibling : parentEle[childEle+1];
                     // what goes here  ?????

                    }
               });
           });
           });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the xml structure but i think we can use modules like xml2json to efficiently parse the xml into json/object structure and use the json for next manipulations. e.g. if we consider below xml,

```
<root>  
 <xxx>
     <txt>{{</txt>
 </xxx>
 <Err type="Start"/>
 <xxx>
     <txt>f</txt>
 </xxx>
 <xxx>
     <txt>irst_name</txt>
 </xxx>
 <Err type="End"/>
 <xxx>
     <txt>}}</txt>
 </xxx>
</root>
```

code to convertinto json will be,

```
  var jsonObj = xml2json(xmlInput);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj, undefined, 4));
```

Out put will be,

```
{
    "root": {
        "xxx": [
            {
                "txt": "{{"
            },
            {
                "txt": "f"
            },
            {
                "txt": "irst_name"
            },
            {
                "txt": "}}"
            }
        ],
        "Err": [
            {
                "type": "Start"
            },
            {
                "type": "End"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```